# Delete duplicates in array but keep first occurrence

Tags: matlab, matrix, duplicates

The following code removes duplicate values

```
numarr = [1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4];
%// Filter doubled values
[n_, bin]       = histc(numarr, unique(numarr));
multiple_       = find(n_ > 1);
mult_indices_   = ismember(bin, multiple_);

numarr(mult_indices_) = [];

%// output     
numarr =  1
```

**How to adapt it, that the *first* occurence of any duplicate remains?**

i.e. that the output will be

```
numarr =

     1     2     3     4
```

Comment: Try matlab's `unique` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`unique`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) with the `'stable'` property:

```
a = [1 3 2 5 2 7 1 3 4 5 6 8 2];
output = unique(a,'stable')
```

which will keep the order and therefore keeps the ***first*** occurrance of every value, as desired.

```
output =

     1     3     2     5     7     4     6     8
```

---

Without `'stable'` the output gets sorted.

---

Regarding your comment: To get the indices of the removed duplicates you need the second output of `unique` and `setdiff`:

```
[output, kept_idx] = unique(a,'stable')
removed_idx = setdiff(1:numel(a),kept_idx)

removed_idx =

     5     7     8    10    13
```

Comment: Nice..what I forgot to mention...is it possible to retrieve the indices of the removed duplicates (i. e. the indices of their locations *before* the have been removed)?

Comment: This I would *not* have figured out myself

Comment: @embert that's what we are here for ;)